Tips for reverse engineering Common Lisp (SBCL) ELF binary
I got to the task of reverse engineering the ELF binary. I found out that it is a compiled SBCL. I have no idea how to do static or dynamic analysis, any tips (where to start, I found basically nothing on the internet)?

I would suggest compiling small helloworld type programs then reversing them yourself to identify boilerplate/runtime vs. user code.
